# How to import one project all components into another react project

Tags: reactjs, package

How can I, `import` one react project components into another `react` project- I have one project that project contains some components ,Now I have created another project using `create-react-app` ,Now my question is how can use first `react` project components in my newly created project

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly `import` components from one project to another. If you'd like to have a reusable component, or better, component library, the best practice is probably to create your component in a different project that you would publish on `npm` and then install this component library in both the projects where you need them.

I guess this article is a good starting point:
https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-create-and-publish-a-react-component-library-2oe

It seems some alternative exists to reuse components from different project, check this link:

https://medium.com/@Powderham/sharing-react-components-between-separate-projects-self-hosting-with-git-installing-with-yarn-npm-d3275b64239c

Comment: Ivo - I don't want to create library

Comment: then copy paste the component...

Comment: Actually there is something Like this but i am not sure how to do it     `"preinstall": "cd ../projectB && npm i && npm run build:local && npm run copy",`   `"my-package": "file:../twilio-video"`

Comment: updated my answer with something that should work. So I wouldn't consider this best practice but probably can help with your case